# regressão multivariada no keras

Tags: regressão, deep-learning, keras

Tenho dois modelos criado no Keras para resolver um problema de regressão multivariada. O primeiro, tem 1 entrada e 5 saídas. O segundo tem uma entrada adicional, ou seja, possui duas entradas e as mesmas 5 saídas. Intuitivamente, o segundo modelo teria um MSE menor que o primeiro devido a entrada adicional, porém, não é o que acontece. O primeiro modelo tem o MSE menor que o segundo, ou seja, tem uma performance melhor. Vocês acham que essa intuição está correta? Como faço para garantir que o segundo modelo tenha um MSE menor?

Answer (score 0):

Faz sentido pensar que quanto mais informações você colocar no modelo, melhor será o seu acerto. Mas isso nem sempre é verdade quando estamos falando de erro de previsão.

Pode ser que incluir essa informação tenha deixado o seu modelo mais específico para a base de treino e menos geral para a base de validação.

Answer (score 0):

A matemática complexa das redes neurais pode gerar confusão no modelo. 
Se esta entrada não contribui significativamente para um melhor resultado, pode ser que ela atrapalhe e "consuma" parte dos neurônios em cálculos que não levam a nada.

Não é raro acontecer isso: adicionar inputs não muito significativos e tornar os modelos piores.

Mas sempre pode estar acontecendo algo mais, é bom checar os bugs, ver se as ativações finais estão compatíveis, etc.

E vale considerar também o "overfitting", caso mencionado pelo @Daniel Falbel na resposta dele.